# Intellij Co-pilot No completions were found issue

Tags: github-copilot

In IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition Github CoPilot stopped providing suggestions, added snapshot below.
[image]

I have tried few items, disable-enable Copilot, and re-caching with restart but no luck so far.

any workaround or suggestion would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this happen to me in Webstorm. After updating the GitHub Copilot plugin, and restarting my IDE, I was able to use Copilot again.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtiG3.png)

as far as I know, you have to write a comment above the code that copilot will generate for you.